# Suddenly Firebase Dynamic Link Does Not Redirect to App Store

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am having a problem where the dynamic link created on the Firebase platform is not redirecting to the App Store if the app is not installed. [Dynamic Link Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZzcf.png)

I have not changed any project settings, and when creating the link I select "If your app is not installed, send the user to App Store page for your app".

Today it just decided to stop working as excepted.

Here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy6BC.png) that I created 2 days back and it works as excepted.

I cannot find any resource on the Firebase website on why this could happen.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, and why are you including flow diagram links? Do they have any relevance to the question?

Comment: @Jay off course the flow diagrams have relevance, that's how one debug dynamic links. maybe you can read more about them here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug). 

All new links being created via firebase dashboard do not redirects to App Store if the app is not installed. I am not sure what part of that question in unclear?

Comment: My question was because the diagrams have no meaning without context. You need to run the diagnostic tool and include *that* information so we know what the flow charts represent. Also including links is discouraged here in SO as links break over time and if they do, it invalidates the question. If the diagrams are relevant, they should be included in the question for reference. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#ios_self-diagnostic_tool) *Tip: Copy the self-diagnostic tool's output when you reach out to Firebase support so we can better help you*

Comment: It has nothing to do with the self diagnostic tool as integration  with iOS is not a problem here. Anyway i have contacted firebase support and its a known issue. They have fixed it but not pushed it to live yet. Thanks.